# Can a Sagemaker endpoint support nested data?

Tags: json, amazon-sagemaker

This has been puzzling me for a while and I may be 'barking up the wrong tree'.

We currently use Sagemaker to make predictions on component failures for certain products in a basic way. This is done fairly simply by training the model and passing "modelcode, manufacture_date, component_code, failure_type" to the endpoint.

The issue is that certain products have trends in component failures and passing the above doesn't include the historic issues with a product in question. e.g. the product may have had 2 component failures that we would predict would lead to a 3rd component failure as other products have had the same issues/trend.

Ideally we would pass nested JSON into the endpoint as follows:

```
{
    "modelcode": "XX001",
    "manufacturedate": "2008.10.08",
    "component_failures":[
     {
           "component_code":"CC001",
           "failure_type":"shattered",
           "failure_date":"2010.01.01",
     }
     {
           "component_code":"CC012",
           "failure_type":"cracked",
           "failure_date":"2012.12.19",
     }
     ]
}
```

Is this possible using AWS Sagemaker or would I have to use an alternative product?

Thanks.

Comment: The input totally depends on the algorithm you deployed? Is it a SageMaker built-in algorithm? if so which? Is it a framework algorithm (tensorflow/mxnet/...)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Sagemaker is very flexible, in that you can customize your own inference code to handle different types of input.

For example, if you are using MXNet as your deep learning framework, you can supply your own inference script and customize it to your own use-case in how to handle the input/output. For more information you can find the detailed explanation here: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_mxnet.html#process-model-input

Similarly there is also one for Tensorflow deep learning framework.

Comment: Just to reiterate what velociraptor11 said, you can customize the inference code which allows you to control the format of your data. SageMaker Endpoints can use any Docker image to do inference so you aren't limited by existing algorithms or models.